# How can I concatenate multiple files into one in Meson?

Tags: meson-build

I'm having trouble with a basic task in Meson where I need multiple files concatenated into one during build; basically:

```
cat *.txt > compiled.txt
```

or

```
cat foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt > compiled.txt
```

However whether I use `custom_target()`, `generator()` or any other function, Meson either can't find the `compiled.txt` or can't handle transitioning from multiple input files to a single output file.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

**Update:**

Using `run_command()` I've managed to build `compiled.txt` and have it appear in the source directory. Ultimately I want `compiled.txt` (which I've listed in the gresource.xml) to be compiled by `gnome.compile_resources()`. Is there a way I can run this command and pass the file directly to that function to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `custom_target()`, pass the output to `dependencies` of `gnome.compile_resources()`. Note you will need a fairly recent `glib` for it to work.

See also: http://mesonbuild.com/Gnome-module.html#gnomecompile_resources

Answer (score 1):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **Solution:**
>
> I ended up not using gresources, but still needed this solution to concatenate files
>
> ```
> cat_prog = find_program('cat')
>
> parts_of_the_whole = files(
>   'part1.txt',
>   'part2.txt'
> )
>
> concat_parts = custom_target(
>   'concat-parts',
>   command: [ cat_prog, '@INPUT@' ],
>   capture: true,
>   input: parts_of_the_whole,
>   output: 'compiled.txt',
>   install_dir: appdatadir,
>   install: true,
>   build_by_default: true
> )
> ```